# Debug error message: Error in solve.default(cov) : 'a' is 0-diml in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R, so I'd appreciate it tremendously if anyone could guide me through this error message, even if its just a tiny hint.
My overal aim is to run the LittleMCAR test from the BaylorEdPsych package.

My dataset contains 3 variables, all numeric.

When I run LittleMCAR(data), I receive this error message: `Error in solve.default(cov) : 'a' is 0-diml`

When I run the debug mode, I receive this information:

```
function (a, b, tol = .Machine$double.eps, LINPACK = FALSE, 
  ...) 
{
  if (is.complex(a) || (!missing(b) && is.complex(b))) {
    a <- as.matrix(a)
    if (missing(b)) {
      b <- diag(1 + (0+0i), nrow(a))
      colnames(b) <- rownames(a)
    }
    return(.Internal(La_solve_cmplx(a, b)))
  }
  if (inherits(a, "qr")) {
    warning("solve.default called with a \"qr\" object: use 'qr.solve'")
    return(solve.qr(a, b, tol))
  }
  a <- as.matrix(a)
  if (missing(b)) {
    b <- diag(1, nrow(a))
    colnames(b) <- rownames(a)
  }
  .Internal(La_solve(a, b, tol))
}
```

There seems to be something wrong with this part:

```
    warning("solve.default called with a \"qr\" object: use 'qr.solve'")
    return(solve.qr(a, b, tol))
  }
```

However, I am not sure how to fix this.

If you'd have any thoughts on this, please share!

Many thanks in advance!

Best wishes,
Noemi

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer myself in the meanwhile. I did not include a variable which can be used to compare the missing values between the variables, such as gender or age.